# Contextual keymaps in Rider

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rider, keymapping

Is it possible to create contextual keymaps (shortcuts) in Rider?

For example, in VS, `F5` is the shortcut for "run in debug mode". Then if you put a breakpoint and it hits, while you're in the debug mode, `F5` will let go and "resume" the execution of the app.

But in Rider it seems like I can't accomplish this - I don't see a way to map `F5` to "Resume" only when I'm attached to the application process. If I map both "Run in debug mode" and "Resume" to `F5` in keymappings, and the breakpoint hits, if I press `F5` to resume, it will instead stop the process, rebuild, run and attach again.

I checked how they envisioned this to work, and they actually mapped `Alt + F5` to "run in debug mode" and `F5` to "resume". But I'd prefer it if I could avoid the `Alt` bit.

Is what I'm looking for possible with Rider, and if so - how?

Thank you.

Comment: tkit, you found any solution or work around, it is really annoying..

Comment: @UttamUghareja Unfortunately no. I had to get a bit creative with how I arranged my shortcuts so nothing overlaps now. If you have an advanced keyboard that supports "layers", that could help a bit, but I assume most people don't and it's not really a Rider solution, more of a workaround..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve the same behavior as in Visual Studio you simply need to remove a shortcut from the "Debug" action and leave it on "Resume Program".

Now you can press F5 and Rider will automatically run a project in the debug mode.

Comment: That's genius and this was driving me nuts.. Take my gold! :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am glad that searching "rider f5 behavior sucks" lead me to this answer. This is such a weird default behavior for an IDE.

Comment: This is not convenient at all.